# How to use custom font files with space in file names

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

i have to add custom font file .Name of file if @"sample font.ttf".I do following steps.
Drop the file (sample font.ttf) into your project.  Open up your Info.plist file, create a key called UIAppFonts and make it an array. Add the filename of the font as a value

But it not working ..I thought the reason may by space in filename.when i get this file it was a compressed with filename @"sample_font.ttf".when i decompress it ,it removes @"_" and get "sample font.ttf"
Then i install it in font book .the name in window is first word file that is "sample"
I try with various way

```
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"sample font" size:14];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"sample" size:14];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"samplefont" size:14];
     UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"samplefont-Bold" size:14];
```

but not working. what exact font name should have to given. ios is 5.0 .Plz help me.

Comment: first install that font in your pc and check what name it is installing in your system. Then give that exact name which is installed in your system in that UIfont pr0perty.

Comment: i tried with that way also that install it first .the name gives is first word of  filename.that is @"sample"

Comment: it works with "Fonts provided by application" instead of using "UIAppFonts" in ios 5.0

Comment: Why don't you use "Fonts provided by application"?

Comment: @Ayaz: As far as my knowledge..."Fonts provided by application" and "UIAppFonts" both are same....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you try in Ios5 I think you forgot to include your font file in TestApp target membershipI

Comment: it works with "Fonts provided by application" instead of using "UIAppFonts" in ios 5.0

Comment: it you want please paste font file name

Comment: @elppa: Thx for your hint about target membership! My font wasn´t there. Finally it works!

Answer (score 3):

Just double click the font file and install it and then it will open Font book
go to `Preview` menu->>`Show font info` 
There you can see the name of the font and use that name in `UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"nameAsSeenInShowFonts" size:14];`

**Note:** The font file name and font name can be different. So in your .plist you use font file name and in your code you use font name

Comment: +1 There is always NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont familyNames]); to find out your font's family name, then NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:kYourFontFamilyFromPreviousLog]);

Answer (score 1):

Except all these, you can use an alternet option for custom fonts. I have implemented this concept jst before some days.
First download [this](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel/downloads). This is FontLabel. Drop it in your project.
***Note that*** If u want to use fonts for label than only this will help u. If so, than u can use FontLabel object instead of ur label object with same behavior.
For exa.

```
FontLabel *label;
label = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 100, 104, 54) fontName:@"Script MT Bold" pointSize:30.0f];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = nil;
[label sizeToFit];
label.opaque = NO;
```

You can treat label object same as ur UILabel object. FontLabel is subclass of UILabel..